# Почему этот ответ является ответом?

Tags: обсуждение, ответы

*Показательно, что вопрос закрыт как дубликат моего же вопроса, написанного почти три года назад. То есть за три года модерация базы знаний никак не изменилась в лучшую сторону, Stack Overflow на русском продолжает быть растущей свалкой бесполезных ответов, и никто не заинтересован как-либо это исправлять.*

---

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1545316

Две мои тревоги были отклонены. Почему?

Открываем [справку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers):

> Ответы, которые совершенно не отвечают на вопрос, могут быть удалены. Это относится к ответам, которые:
>
> - являются комментарием к вопросу или ответом **на совсем другой вопрос**;
> - ...
> - даже частично не отвечают на фактический вопрос.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149148/discussion-on-question-by-andreymal-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer) или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 6):

Картинка взята из широко известного в узких кругах ответа на вопрос от том, ["что есть not an answer" c Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/2452869).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ключевые моменты из этого же поста с моим вольным переводом:

> You flag as NAA things posted as answers that ***clearly and obviously*** do not attempt to answer an on-topic question or the question asked.
>
> Использовать флаг "не является ответом" нужно на ответы, которые ***ясно и очевидно*** не **пытаются** отвечать на поставленный вопрос (который подходит по тематике сообщества).

В переводе я выделил "ясно и очевидно". Очевидно и ясно должно быть не только человеку, который ставит флаг, но и любому модератору, который может понятия не иметь о конкретной технологии, использующейся в вопросе.

Также:

> Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers or answers that use a different programming language. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
>
> Любой пост, который пытается ответить на вопрос, неважно насколько плохо, все равно является ответом. Не используйте флаг "не является ответом" для неправильных ответов или ответов, которые используют другой язык программирования. **Модераторы не оценивают техническую корректность ответа**.

Исходя из этого, ваш флаг нужно отклонять. Правильное действие (если вы считаете ответ плохим) - "голос вниз".

Краткая мотивация:

- нагрузка на модераторов будет огромной, если начать ставить такие флаги.
- "ясно и очевидно" - должно трактоваться с максимально строгой стороны. Модератор не должен обладать НИКАКОЙ технической экспертизой по вопросы, чтобы принять решение об утверждении флага.
- для таких ситуаций уже есть кнопка "голования против".

Comment: Модератор не должен обладать никакой технической экспертизой, чтобы прочитать первую строчку «ответа» и понять, что автор **ясно и очевидно** отказался от попытки ответить на вопрос.

Comment: @andreymal я с вами не согласен. Если бы такой флаг был поставлен в сообществе, которое модерирую я - он был бы отклонен.

Comment: И это ставит под сомнение вашу компетентность как модератора

Comment: @andreymal ок. это одна из возможных интерпретаций.

Comment: Продолжая аналогию с картинки — автор ответа невнимательно поглядел на вопрос, увидел в нём «апельсины» и решил написать, как их «вырастить». В итоге вопрос про «как достать вот эти яблоки», а ответ про «как вырастить свои апельсины». И, опять же, техническая экспертиза для этого не нужна, это всё понятно сразу из первой строчки ответа

Comment: (продолжаю продолжать, простите https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXiUD.jpg)

Comment: @andreymal тоже повторюсь. Я прочитал вопрос, прочитал ответ и далеко не сразу понял, что ответ - это про апельсины. Мне пара минут потребовалась, чтобы вообще понять, что ответ скорее не соответствует этому вопросу даже читая имеющиеся комментарии. Следовательно, критерий "ясность и очевидность" - не выполнен.

Comment: Что ещё раз ставит под сомнение вашу компетентность как модератора, раз вы даже не удосужились вникнуть в текст вопроса и в текст ответа. Зачем сайту непонимающие модераторы?

Comment: @andreymal советую в таком случае писать напрямую в SE или поднимать тему на мете Computational Science SE или на общей мете о моей некомпетенстности.

Comment: Мне кажется подобная настойчивость достойна лучшего применения, чем воевать за удаление мало кому интересного ответа. Например можно было бы и ответ улучшить, и правильный дать ..

Comment: @Kromster очистка базы знаний от мусора - одна из достойных деятельностей на сайте (для этого и существуют закрытия вопросов, очереди проверок, тревоги и другие инструменты), но сообщество и модераторы дружно настаивают, что в базе знаний нужно обязательно копить мусор

Comment: "флаг" -> "тревога"

Comment: @andreymal вы больше мусора этими бессмысленными спорами плодите, чем тот ответ. Успокойтесь уже. Сообщество против, и всё.

Comment: @Зонтик никакого мусора не будет, если сообщество не будет сопротивляться очистке базы знаний от мусора

Comment: @andreymal "сообщество не будет сопротивляться" - кому сопротивляться? Мы здесь сами всё решаем. И решили (+0/-4), что ответ не надо удалять, а достаточно заминусовать.

Comment: @Зонтик ну вот мы и вернулись к моему предыдущему комментарию — «сообщество и модераторы дружно настаивают, что в базе знаний нужно обязательно копить мусор»

Comment: @Зонтик, не +0/-4, а +2/-6.

Comment: @wchistow тогда было иначе.